# rm -rf not erasing directory

Tags: linux, command-line

I am attempting to erase a directory called apps.  When I run rm-rf apps it looks like it erases it for the moment.  When I log back on to the server the directory is still there, though it is highlighted in green.

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 user user 4096 2010-04-24 18:33 apps
```

Comment: Most likely something else is recreating it.

Answer (score 2):

Could there be a process that is creating that directory for you?

Answer (score 1):

Is the directory empty? If it so, you could try with rmdir: if again it fails, you could try to contact the server admin.

Comment: I love 'please contact your system administrator' messages I AM THE F*ing administrator.

Comment: ahahah, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

What system are you running? Does your system support the immutable or undeletable flags? If it's supported, and set, you'll get this exact result.

On my system, `chflags noschg nouchg` will remove the system and user immutable flags; and `chflags nosunlnk nouunlnk` removes the system and user undeletable flags. The commands on other systems may be different.

Answer (score 1):

first Check the created/modified time for the directory using '`ls -l`' ( or you can use `stat <dir>`) and remove the directory '`rm -rf dir`' and again check the times. If there is any changes in time, there is some other process creating it. If so check for any running process using '`ps -ef`' which may creating this directory again.

Answer (score 0):

It may have been the remnant of a git repository that kept regenerating itself.  I restarted the linode (my VPS) and it seems to have resolved itself.

Comment: This sort of thing should probably be left as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @david: if this is what solved his problem it should be posted as an answer.  @chief: if you register your Stack Overflow and Super User accounts and associate them together you'll regain ownership of this question.

Comment: @quack: well... it doesn't really answer the question, just says that the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

The critical permissions are on the directory containing apps.  Suppose it is in /spare/apps, but you do not have write permission in the /spare directory, then the 'rm' command will remove everything it can, but it is unable to do the final step because removing /spare/apps involves writing to /spare, and (under my hypothesis) you do not have permission to  write there.